# Why can't Monks equip two-handed maces?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

Every two-handed mace I find shows a red X for my Monk, as well as a red box around my current weapon in my inventory. The maces do not show class restrictions (example below). Are Monks unable to equip certain non-class restricted weapons?

[image: mace]
[image: mace]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. There are certain non-class specific weapons that your monk is not allowed to use. A few such weapons are:

- Bows
- Crossbows
- Two-Handed Swords
- Two-Handed Axes
- Two-Handed Maces

I do not believe there is ever any explicit reason in-game as to why the Monk cannot use them, however.